# writeFileSync only write half of data

Tags: node.js, csv, fs

So i encountered a problem while doing my project.The problem is that when i try to write my data to csv file,it only write half of the data ,even sometimes only less than half of my data.I don't know what the problem is because there is no error shown in the terminal.

Below is my code

```
async function getFile(req, res, next) {

    try {
        let URI;
        const listOfKeys = await listAllKeys();
        let temp = []

        await Promise.all(listOfKeys.map(async function (data) {
            let response = await writeFile(data.Key);
            temp.push(response)
        }))
            .then(async _ => {
                fs.writeFileSync(FILE_PATH, Buffer.concat(temp));
            })
            .catch(err => {
                console.log(err)
            })
        return res.json({ message: 'halo' });
    } catch (err) {
        console.log('hmm.... error', err);
        return next(new APIError(err, httpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR, true));
    };
};
```

And this is the writeFile function

```
function writeFile(key) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        s3.getObject({ Bucket: process.env.AWS_BUCKET, Key: key }, (err, data) => {
            if (err) reject(err)
            else resolve(data.Body)
        })
    });
};
```

If possible, i would like to know the detail of my problem and how to fix it.Thanks.

Comment: Somewhat misleading code.  Your `writeFile()` function has a completely wrong name.  It should be something like `getData()` and your `getFile()` function should be something like `getDataAndWriteToFile()`.

Comment: Also, you call `return res.json()` long before your operation is done.  And, you should not be using the synchronous `fs.writeFileSync()` in a request handler.

Comment: hey @jfriend00 ,i'm pretty much aware with the wrong name of my function and would fix it later once i solve my writing data problem,thank you for noticing.I have tried to move `res.json()` inside `fs.writeFile()` callback,but it doesn't fix my problem.So i would like to know,is there any way to check if the `fs.writeFile()` operation is done ? Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks to me like you can do it like this (function names have been modified to make sense to me):

```
const fsp = require('fs').promises;

async function getDataAndWriteFile(req, res, next) {
    try {
        let URI;
        const listOfKeys = await listAllKeys();

        let responses = await Promise.all(listOfKeys.map(function (data) {
            return getData(data.Key);
        }));
        await fsp.writeFile(FILE_PATH, Buffer.concat(responses);
        res.json({ message: 'halo' });
    } catch(err) {
        console.log('hmm.... error', err);
        next(new APIError(err, httpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR, true));
    }
}

function getData(key) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        s3.getObject({ Bucket: process.env.AWS_BUCKET, Key: key }, (err, data) => {
            if (err) reject(err)
            else resolve(data.Body)
        })
    });
}
```

Summary of changes:

1. Change function names to better describe what they do
2. Use `let responses = await Promise.all()` to get the data from the promise array.
3. Use the promise interface in the `fs` module with `await fsp.writeFile()` to write the data out to your file.
4. Use try/catch to catch all the promise rejections in one place

Possible Open Issues:

1. Writing this `Buffer.concat(responses)` to disk seems kind of odd.  Is that really what you want in this file?

Comment: Hey,i try your code and i got error saying `cannot read property 'writeFile' of undefined`.I use `Buffer.concat` because i want to combine all the buffer response and write it into one file,But i think  with your code i don't need `Buffer.concat` anymore,since i assume it already combine all response buffer.

Comment: @ImanuelJodi - What version of node.js are you running?  The `fs.promises` interface is a newer feature (though not that new).  `responses` is an array of `getData()` calls so you can't just write the array directly unless you convert it to JSON so you will have to do something to process the array before writing it to disk.

Comment: I'm currently using node version 8.11.3,i'll try to upgrade it,but the flow of the project has change,so i'm not writing the file in to disk anymore.Thank you so much for helping :) @jfriend00

Comment: @ImanuelJodi - Well, let's try to finish off this question so it's not left hanging here.  You can either accept the answer as is (click the checkmark to the left of the answer) or I can add how to make it work on your older version of node?

Comment: Hey after i upgrade my node version,it starts working,so i think i will accept your solution as the answer.Thank you for helping me. @jfriend00